# Living room light, bedroom and AC switch are not working. I checked both switch, both have power coming in also the neutral. Lost of neutral

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, neutral

It was a generator
Well I checked the distribution board for power which was there in all the breakers. The neutral had light in it when tasted with a tester so I left to check the wire for the light, pulled one out use a testing lamp but no light come out also with the AC switch the input have power in both live and neutral but the output have nothing in both for the AC power switch. The lighting switch have power in them but I just don't know how to locate this issue.

Comment: Electricity is simple, it goes out one wire(hot/black) and comes back on the other(white/neutral) if there are no breaks/broken wire.  A switch breaks the circuit(and should be the only break point).  If power at the switch, but not pass it(at the light), you have a break(probably loose connection) between the switch and the light.  Check the lights are not burned out and check the connections(with power off at main breaker panel/generator off).

Comment: The question is not very clear but a common problem with window AC units is they are heavy loads like electric heaters and heavy loads can cause back stab failures or any weak link in a daisy chain as is common for window units if the circuit is hot the neutral is open so the circuit can not be completed. Checking receptacles with a plug in light or hair dryer can narrow down the problem, this type of failure is at the last working receptacle (or switch) or first non working receptacle. This is a common electrical problem probably #1 in numbers of failures.